# Why is this a fragment sentence?

Tags: sentence-fragments

Why is this a fragment sentence?

- *Indicate that antibacterial soaps may wash away useful bacteria.*

Comment: Has no subject. Is a problem.

Comment: Can someone help me understand why this question should be closed?  I'm still trying to get the hang of what to close and what not to close.  What's wrong with this question?

Comment: The title should be "Why is sentence fragment?"

Comment: Title should be “Why sentence fragment?” – [Frankenstein](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/26083/scott) Oct 10 '16 at 3:18                ⁠

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it's not a sentence fragment.  It's in the [imperative mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) (i.e., it's a command), but it doesn't make much sense that somebody would ever say that.

"**Studies** indicate that antibacterial soaps may wash away useful bacteria", on the other hand, is a well-formed sentence that makes sense.  I'm guessing that your (textbook, teacher, ?) wants that.

Comment: Nicely done; I would never have imagined it as an impertaive, but it can clearly be seen that way. +1

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense as an instruction to someone trying to convince people not to buy antibacterial hand soap? Upvote from me too.

Comment: @deadrat I suppose it could be written in a medical manual.  But I think I'd use a different verb than *indicate*.  "Hey, you!  Yes, you.  Indicate that antibacterial soaps may wash away useful bacteria.  Go on, indicate it!"

Comment: @JohnFeltz I'm gong to wash my hands of this whole matter.